# Nodejs: dose not show abstract object in swagger

Tags: node.js, typescript, swagger

I Have Dto file like this:

```
export class workflowDto {
    @ApiProperty()
    @IsNotEmpty({message: i18nValidationMessage('validation.NOT_EMPTY')})
    data: {
    connection: object
    nodes: object
    parameters:object,
    front: object
    }
 }
```

in swagger, it show me this:

```
 {
   "data": {
   "connection": {},
   "nodes": {},
   "parameters": {},
  "front": {}
},
```

but when I change my Dto file to this:

```
export interface Data {
connection: object
nodes: object
parameters:object,
front: object
}


export class workflowDto {
    @ApiProperty()
    @IsNotEmpty({message: i18nValidationMessage('validation.NOT_EMPTY')})
    data: Data
}
```

swagger show me this:

```
{
  "data": {},
}
```